# Writing a String to a webpage in Android

Tags: java, android, server, mobile-application

I'm trying to write a String to my webpage using Java in Android Studio by reusing some piece of codes of one Java Eclipse project which works well on my PC.

However, the String just cannot be written to the web page using my Android phone.

```
    public void upload(String FTPaddress, String message){
        try {
           URL url = new URL(FTPaddress);                           // my server address
           URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();   
           OutputStream os = (OutputStream) urlc.getOutputStream(); // To upload 
           OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(os);

           buffer.write(message.getBytes());
           buffer.close();
           os.close();
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // print in log 
           } catch (IOException e) {
                    // print in log
           }
     }
```

*Please note that the function is executed, the mobile phone is connected to the internet, thus I am running it on another thread using `asyncTask`, and there is no exceptions*

So can anyone tell me why it worked on my laptop but not for my mobile phone?

Comment: You may want to add some logging to check the connection state, etc. Perhaps some information can be gleaned that way. Perhaps the mobile connects via passive and desktop uses ftp active connection? More information would certainly help narrow things down.

Comment: did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to begining of manifest.xml ?

Comment: You may need to call setDoOutput method before establishing connection http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setDoOutput(boolean)

Comment: @kazuki   I set the method to be true and it works perfectly now!!   Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Tomek I have that in my manifest, and Thanks for your help